# route results from yield to a file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following Python script using Scrapy:

```
import scrapy


class ChemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "site"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.site.com.au'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        category_links = response.css('li').xpath('a/@href').getall()
        category_links_filtered = [x for x in category_links if 'shop-online' in x] # remove non category links
        category_links_filtered = list(dict.fromkeys(category_links_filtered)) # remove duplicates 

        for category_link in category_links_filtered:
            if "medicines" in category_link:
                next_page = response.urljoin(category_link) + '?size=10'
                self.log(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_subcategories)

    def parse_subcategories(self, response):
        for product in response.css('div.Product'):
            yield {
                'category_link': response.url,
                'product_name': product.css('img::attr(alt)').get(),
                'product_price': product.css('span.Price::text').get().replace('\n','')
            }
```

My solution will run multiple instances of this script, each scraping a different subset of information from different 'categories'. I know you can run scrapy from the command line to output to a json file, but i want do to the output to a file from within the function, so each instance writes to a different file. Being a beginner with Python, I'm not sure where to go with my script. I need to get the output of the yield into a file while the script is executing. How do i achieve this? There will be hundreds of rows scraped, and I'm not familiar enough with how yield works to understand how to 'return' from it a set of data (or a list) that can then be written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to append a file. But being file writing an I/O operation, you need to lock the file from being written by other processes while a process is writing.

Easiest way to achieve is to write in different random files (files with random names) in a directory and concatenating them all using another process.

Answer (score 0):

First let me suggest you some changes to your code. If you want to remove duplicates i you could use a `set` like this:

```
category_links_filtered = (x for x in category_links if 'shop-online' in x) # remove non category links
category_links_filtered = set(category_links_filtered) # remove duplicates
```

note that i'm also changing the `[` to `(` to make a **generator** instead of a **list** and save some memory. Search more about **generators**: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_generators.php

OK then the solution for your problem is using an **Item Pipeline** (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), what this does perfom some action on every item yielded from your function `parse_subcategories`. What you do is add a class in your `pipelines.py` file and enable this pipeline in `settings.py`. This is:

- In `settings.py`:

  ```
  ITEM_PIPELINES = {
      'YOURBOTNAME.pipelines.CategoriesPipeline': 300, #the number here is the priority of the pipeline, dont worry and just leave it
  }
  ```
- In `pipelines.py`:

  ```
  import json
  from urlparse import urlparse #this is library to parse urls

  class CategoriesPipeline(object):
      #This class dynamically saves the data depending on the category name obtained in the url or by an atrtribute
      def open_spider(self, spider):
          if hasattr(spider, 'filename'):
              #the filename is an attribute set by -a filename=somefilename
              filename = spider.filename
          else:
              #you could also set the name dynamically from the start url like this, if you set -a start_url=https://www.site.com.au/category-name
              try:
                  filename = urlparse(spider.start_url).path[1:] #this returns 'category-name' and replace spaces with _
              except AttributeError:
                  spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='no start url') #this should not happen
          self.file = open(filename+'.jl', 'w')

      def close_spider(self, spider):
          self.file.close()

      def process_item(self, item, spider):
          line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
          self.file.write(line)
          return item
  ```
- In `spiders/YOURBOTNAME.py` modify this:

  ```
  class ChemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = "site"
      if !hasattr(self, 'start_url'):
          spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='no start url') #we need a start url
      start_urls = [ self.start_url ] #see why this works on https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests

      def parse(self, response):#...
  ```

and then you start your crawl with this command: `scrapy crawl site -a start_url=https://www.site.com.au/category-name` and you could optionally add `-a filename=somename`

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I will review your suggestions in detail, but on the first point can i understand why the method I used to remove duplicates is not suitable? From my beginner level reading I understood conversion to a dictionary to be a valid way to remove duplicates in Python as dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. Is this a bad way to achieve this?

Comment: You are creating a more complex object (dictionary) with all its values None (see what dict.fromkeys does) but inside the dictionary is using a set to avoid duplicates. Anyways, is a waste of memory and time to make an object if you won't use it totally

Comment: Okay, I understand. So it's more the fact that both solutions will achieve the same aim, but if memory is constrained or the performance time is a critical factor, your option would be the better of the two. Thanks Ivan. I'll review the rest of your suggestions now.